# Two Laravel Apps interfering on virtual host (XAMPP)

Tags: laravel, xampp

I have 2 Laravel apps located in htdocs on XAMPP. Each of them have a virtual hosts setting like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/app1/public"
    ServerName app1.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/app2/public"
    ServerName app2.test
</VirtualHost>
```

with proper settings in etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 app1.test
127.0.0.1 app2.test
```

But for some reason the are interfering with each other, for example seems that .env values for the database are jumbled up, since database from app1 is referencing a table from database from app2 and this error appears:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'some_table' doesn't exist
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try restarting your apache?

Comment: Yes, after every change, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use very friendly package called as **Laragon** rather than XAMPP.
In this package you can use ****multiple php versions** with same database along with ssl**. Also you can whatever you need with **Laragon CMD**.

Here is the link for Laragon setup
[Laragon setup](https://laragon.org/download/)